# Sublime Text 2 / Windows: launch from command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, sublime-text-2

How could one invoke Sublime Text from the command line, so that it starts in the current folder? (I'm using the MINGW32 that comes with Git on Windows)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One solution might be to make an alias to fire up sublime to edit a file:

```
alias edit='c:/Program\ Files/sublime\ text\ 2/sublime_text.exe -w'
```

So one can do something like:

```
cd c:/repos/test/
edit test.html
```

Sublime should open up, and after save+close it should go back to the command prompt.

Comment: For what it's worth, on other platforms sublime includes a "subl" command to do exactly this. If you want to be consistent, you should probably use that instead of "edit".

Comment: What does "-w" mean?

Comment: The `-w` means

`-w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning` 

See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html