# Launch Sublime Text 2 from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, sublime-text-2

I am trying to launch Sublime Text 2 via command line.

I know it has already been done before [here](https://superuser.com/questions/428727/sublime-text-2-windows-launch-from-command-line) but I am having different constraints. I use the portable version of ST and store it into my Dropbox account. I guess you can see me coming here.

I need to launch subtext on a relative path. So far it "kinda works" if I type in the command line `subl file.txt` it works I see the file content but if I type `subl "file 2.txt"` I do not have nothing it opens ST with something like `c:\mydir\"file 2.txt"`.

I guess the problem lies on the `"%WORKINGDIR%\%1"` of the script bellow.

```
@ECHO OFF  
SET WORKINGDIR=%CD%  
cd /d %0\..  
SET EXECDIR=%CD%  
cd %WORKINGDIR%  
START "Sublime text editor" "%EXECDIR%\sublimetext\sublime_text.exe" "%WORKINGDIR%\%1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally was able to solve that problem.

I had to update the batch file like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET WORKINGDIR=%CD%
cd /d %~dp0
SET EXECDIR=%CD%
cd %WORKINGDIR%
START "Sublime text editor" "%EXECDIR%\sublimetext\sublime_text.exe" "%WORKINGDIR%\%~1"
```

Basically, using `%~dp0` for the `execdir` and `%~1` for the file to launch were sufficient enough to do the trick.